# Awk/grep/sed get comma separated list of numbers from lines of text

Tags: command-line, sed, grep, awk

I have a log file that has lines that look like this:

```
blah blah blah Photo for (702049679 - blah blah blah
```

Now I know I could get all the lines like that from the file by doing:

```
grep "Photo for" logFile
```

But how can I take those lines and get a comma seperated list of each number after the parenthesis in a single output line (these are going to be pasted into an SQL query)?

The numbers in question will be the first occurrence of a string of numeric characters 9 or more digits long.  Ideally it could be matched using that criteria, or the criteria of the first number occurring after the "Photo for (" text.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the input data? `blah blah blah` is pretty nondescript and vague...

Comment: @jasonwryan Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex this complicated is better handled with Perl, e.g.

```
grep "Photo for" logFile | perl -pe 's/.*Photo for ((\d+).*/\1/' | tr '\n' ','
```

If Perl is out of the question:

```
grep "Photo for" logFile | awk '{sub(/.*Photo for \(/,"",$0);sub(/[ ].*/,"");print $0}' | tr '\n' ','
```

Comment: First one works... second one gives `awk: fatal: Unmatched ( or \(: /.*Photo for (/`. Thanks though, problem solved. EDIT: Second just needs that parenthesis escaped with \.

Comment: I fixed the second answer (I added "Photo for" to the regex at the last minute when you edited the post)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that uses only Perl and matches the criteria you specified:

```
perl -ne '
    /Photo for/ && /([0-9]{9,})/ && push @numbers,$1;
    END{ $" = ","; print "@numbers" }
' logFile
```

This will print out a comma-separated list of the first occurrence of a contiguous digit string made up of 9 or more digits on each line matching `Photo for`.

Answer (score 0):

1) need gnu grep

```
grep -iPo "(?<=Photo for \()[0-9]+" logFile|tr "\n" ","
```

2) Using awk

```
awk -F \( '/Photo for/{split($2,a,OFS);printf a[1] ","}' logFile
```